# MySQL Query to find the ids in table that are not in the list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of some 1000 ids among which only few ids are not in the table. I need to fetch the ids from the list which are not in table.
I don't have access to create tables or insert data into that table.

```
create table t1(id int);
insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);
```

Now i need to get details of the ids that are not in the table but in the where clause.

```
where clause - id in (2,5,8,9,25)
```

my output should be 8,9,25

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this using sql?

Comment: yeah...solving with sql will help in a great manner

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering since this means you have to hard code "some 1000 id's"  in an sql query. Sounds very error prone to me

Answer (score 4):

Don't put them in a `where` clause.  Use a derived table with a `left join` or similar construct:

```
select i.id
from (select 2 as id union all
      select 5 as id union all
      select 8 as id union all
      select 9 as id union all
      select 25 as id
     ) i
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = i.id);
```

Comment: But when we have 1000's of records in the where clause, it is not feasible to append the ids with select and execute the query. That was one of the main problem

Comment: @VinayGurram . . . If you can put them in a `WHERE` clause, you can put them in a derived table.  If that is a problem, then you should use a subquery so they are not passed in from the application.

Comment: They are not passed from the application. This is for issue debugging purpose where the values in the where clause changes frequently

Comment: @VinayGurram . . . I would recommend that you store them in a table.

Comment: For storing them in a table, i will be needing write access which is not given for developers. so, i have to try to achieve it in the select query itself..thats the toughest job here.